# How do async redux functions work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-redux

I started learning redux in reactjs. I am trying to implement an async structure to redux but I am really confused...

To implement an async function and use the promise you should type async before your function and use await before using the promise.

But in many examples I never saw they use of async before functions and await before the promise variables.

For example look at these two links:

https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/async

So how can I call async function in the reducer and return the async results?

For example, I want to prepare this list with an async function and get the list with axios or fetch API :

```js
const list = [
    {id: 1, title: 'One'},
    {id: 2, title: 'Two'},
    {id: 3, title: 'Three'}
]

export function newsReducer(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_NEWS':
            return list
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: why dont you use either thunk or redux-saga?

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier No, I should search about those and learn more, Thank you

Answer (score 2):

To summarize it I would suggest, to understand this concepts action, reducer and store.

- An action is a trigger for one or more reducer cases
- the store is on and all the data is contained and only reduceres can change it using the method they get from the store 'dispatch'
- reducer is a piece of code that produces immutable changes on the store.

So in order to do a change to the store synchronically you have to call the store method `dispatch` such that the reducer triggers and changes what you expect.

To do async you will have to call the reducere when the async call is done.

Example:

```
   // action method called by react component when user submits changes
    export function updateProduct(product) {
        // returns a function since this method has to be called also with dispatch() in the component
        return dispatch => {
            // trigger first store change
            dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_EDIT.PRODUCT_EDIT_REQUEST });

            // trigger secod store change and mark the async call, updateProduct is ASYNC
            ProductsService.updateProduct(product)
                .then(
                    res => {
                        dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_EDIT.PRODUCT_EDIT_SUCCESS, data: res.data });
                        dispatch(successNotification('Product updated'));
                    },
                    error => {
                        dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_EDIT.PRODUCT_EDIT_FAILURE, data: error.response.data  });
                        dispatch(errorNotification(error.response.data));
                    }
                );
        };
    }
```

Other tutorials I think you should check:
https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/step-by-step-guide-to-building-react-redux-apps-using-mocks-48ca0f47f9a

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to use `redux-thunk` like @ Sujit.Warrier suggested in the comment here is a small and simple example that can get you started using `redux-thunk`.

```
export const getlist =()=> dispatch =>{
   fetch(`api link for your list`).then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
              dispatch({type:'GET_NEWS' , payload:data})
            });
};
```

and then you can dispatch the function in your component